# What is Tophat prior?

Tags: distributions, bayesian, prior, hyperparameter

I constantly run into Tophat prior being mentioned as a prior for certain hyperparameters (prior for kernel length scales for example), but I have never seen its analytical expression or have read about the reasoning behind such prior choice. Could someone explain what Tophat prior is?

Comment: Do you mean a notation like $\mathbf{\hat{p}}$? A hat on a parameter usually just means that it is an estimate of that parameter. For instance you could use Maximum Likelihood to get an estimate of some prior. Maybe you could give some more context

Comment: This is one of the papers that mentioned Tophat prior: [C. Pryke et al.](https://arxiv.org/pdf/astro-ph/0104490.pdf) . It is mentioned at the end of 3rd page. To me it seemed like a uniform prior, but I guess I did not understand something.

Comment: Could it be that they are talking about top-hat filters (and top-hat prior would refer to the prior of such)? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Top-hat_filter

Comment: It's essentially a uniform prior over a fixed range, so when you make a graph of it, it looks like a top hat.  In the context of the paper you cited, if you are calculating the distribution over a grid of values, the grid itself acts as an implicit top-hat prior - you won't see values larger than the largest grid value or smaller than the smallest, and each grid value, by virtue of its existence, has an implicit weight of "1" in some sense.

Comment: @jbowman I never notice the name used before, you should probably make an answer out of your comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's essentially a uniform prior over a fixed range, so when you make a graph of it, it looks like a top hat. In the context of the paper you cited, if you are calculating the distribution over a grid of values, the grid itself acts as an implicit top-hat prior - you won't see values larger than the largest grid value or smaller than the smallest, and each grid value, by virtue of its existence, has an implicit weight of "1" in some sense.